# UILabel doesn't seem to update as time data changes

Tags: ios, swift

I've spent the last couple of months learning swift and thought I'd have a go at making a multi timer, please forgive any rookie errors! I have created a timer class which receives the input data from the user and handles the countdown. This all seems to be working fine however the label which displays the time remaining only ever updates when I click the start button. 
The code for my timer class is as follows:

```
class TimerClass: NSObject {

    var timer = NSTimer ()
    var startTimeCounter:NSTimeInterval = 0
    var hours = Int?()
    var minutes = Int?()
    var seconds = Int?()
    var timeString = String()
    var firstCheck:Bool = true

    func getTime() {
        // check if user has already clicked start so as to not double up the decrement
        if firstCheck == true {
            startTimeCounter += (NSTimeInterval(hours!) * 3600)
            startTimeCounter += (NSTimeInterval(minutes!) * 60)
            startTimeCounter += NSTimeInterval(seconds!)
            firstCheck = false
        }
        else {
            firstCheck = false
        }
        // turn the user data into hrs mins secs
        var timeRemaining : NSTimeInterval = startTimeCounter

        var hoursInt = Int(timeRemaining / 3600.0)
        timeRemaining -= (NSTimeInterval(hoursInt) * 3600)

        var minutesInt = Int(timeRemaining / 60.0)
        timeRemaining -= (NSTimeInterval(minutesInt) * 60)

        var secondsInt = Int(timeRemaining)
        timeRemaining -= NSTimeInterval(secondsInt)

        var strHours = String(format: "%02d", hoursInt)
        var strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutesInt)
        var strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", secondsInt)
        // create a string for the label
        timeString = "\(strHours):\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"
    }

    func updateTime () {
        startTimeCounter -= 1
        getTime()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector:#selector(TimerClass.updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }


}
```

Also my view controller looks like this:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var timeRemainingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var setDoneButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var secStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var minStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var hourStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var secLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var setView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var timerLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var setButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!


    var hourSelected = Int()
    var minSelected = Int()
    var secSelected = Int()
    var newTimer:TimerClass = TimerClass()
    var startPressed:Bool = false



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // Set button pressed
    @IBAction func setPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.setView.alpha = 0.8
    }

    // User closed set menu
    @IBAction func setDonePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.setView.alpha = 0
        newTimer.hours = Int(self.hourStepper.value)
        newTimer.minutes = Int(self.minStepper.value)
        newTimer.seconds = Int(self.secStepper.value)
        newTimer.getTime()
    }

    // Stepper functions
    @IBAction func hourStepperPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.hourLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", hourStepper.value)
    }

    @IBAction func minStepperPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.minLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", minStepper.value)
    }

    @IBAction func secStepperPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.secLabel.text = String(format: "%.0f", secStepper.value)
    }

    // User pressed start
    @IBAction func startPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.newTimer.startTimer()
        updateTimerLabel()
        startPressed = true
    }

    func updateTimerLabel () {
        timeRemainingLabel.text = newTimer.timeString
    }
}
```

I appreciate that I have probably gone the long way around this problem but it is my first independent app so I'm still getting my head around things!

Comment: And what exactly do you expect? You're calling `updateTimerLabel` once, in the `startPressed` method. Shouldn't you maybe call it in the timer's target method?

Comment: You're not calling a function that updates the label. Sounds like you think the label should change, just because the value you set the labels value to changes. That's (in some cases, sadly) not how it works. You have to set the labels text each time timer changes

Comment: Ah OK, so would the target method be in the timer class itself? I haven't been able to update the label from within the class, do I need to use a delegate or something so I can access the timerLabel.text within the class?

Comment: You won't want to update your view controllers label from within the timer class. On each timer tick you should delegate the responsibility of updating the UI back to your view controller. This keeps your timer class reusable as you don't have any ties to your specific view controller. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only updating your UI when the user selects the done button.

One way to not have another timer is for your TimerClass to tell your view controller that it needs to update the UI.

You can create a protocol in your TimerClass, and set your view controller as the timers 'delegate' object.

Something like this:

```
protocol TimerDelegate: class {
    /**
    * Tell the delegate to update the interface
    **/
    func updateUI()
}

class TimerClass: NSObject {  
    var timer = NSTimer ()
    ...
    var firstCheck:Bool = true

    weak var delegate: TimerDelegate?

    func getTime() {
        ///
    }

    func updateTime () {
        startTimeCounter -= 1
        getTime()
        delegate?.updateUI()
    }

    func startTimer() {
        ...
    }
}
```

And then your view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, TimerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var timeRemainingLabel: UILabel!
    ...
    @IBOutlet weak var pauseButton: UIButton!

    var hourSelected = Int()
    ...
    var startPressed:Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        newTimer.delegate = self
    }

    // Set button pressed
    @IBAction func setPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        ...
    }

    // User closed set menu
    @IBAction func setDonePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        ...
    }

    // Stepper functions
    @IBAction func hourStepperPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        ...

    }
    @IBAction func minStepperPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        ...
    }
    @IBAction func secStepperPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        ...
    }

    //MARK: TimerDelegate

    func updateUI() {
        updateTimerLabel()
    }

    // User pressed start
    @IBAction func startPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        self.newTimer.startTimer()
        updateTimerLabel()
        startPressed = true
    }

    func updateTimerLabel () {
        timeRemainingLabel.text = newTimer.timeString
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked a charm! I had been thinking maybe I have to use a delegate but I'm not too familiar with them yet. Thank you so much for your help.
I guess I'd better do some research on delegates now.

Comment: Perfect answer and already upvoted, I just want to add a little input on it: calling "updateUI" from a delegate means that the timer knows it is called from a UI component.
To create a generic timer, it is useful to not give him information like that, so it is better to create a protocol method like "didUpdate" and in its implementation decide what to do. In this way the timer continue to have one functionality, but it is generic and can be used with UI component, logic component and so on. Btw, good improvement after 2 months only :)

Comment: @Marco Pace You're correct, that would of made the answer better!